# Find Top Big Family

Tags: mysql

I have this database with 7 columns

**

> First-name || date-birth || place-birth || name-of_father || sex ||
>   last-name

**

What I've tried:

```
String SQL="select name-of_father,last-name,Count(*) from tab a
                where name-of_father in ( select name-of_father from tab b
                                       where a.name-of_father=b.name-of_father);
```

What I want is how can I find ?

1-Top Big Family(select name-of_father,last-name,Count(number of childs).

2-the family who has the most numbers of boys.

If anyone help me I'll be very grateful.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Answer (score 1):

> Top Big Family(select name-of_father,last-name,Count(number of
>   childs).

Query should be something like.

**Query**

```
 SELECT 
   father.`First-name`
 , father.`last-name`
 , COUNT(*) AS number_of_childeren
FROM 
 table father
INNER JOIN
 table childeren
ON
 father.`First-name` = childeren.`name-of_father`
ORDER BY
 COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

> the family who has the most numbers of boys.

Query should be something like.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
   `last-name`
 , COUNT(*) AS number_of_males
FROM 
 table
WHERE 
 sex = 'male'
GROUP BY 
  `last-name`
ORDER BY
  COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```